# JavaFX table individual row height, cannot set low values

Tags: javafx

Using the code below I wanted to set low values for the row height of a JavaFx table. But to me there seems to be a limit of about 25, higher values will show up correctly, but not below about 25.

I could use `setFixedCellSize(10)` to set all rows of a table. I would be interested in doing it for individual rows, so I think this should be done in TableCell, right?

Is there a way to get like a row height of 15?

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableCellTest extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
    @Override public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        int numCols = 20;
        int numRows = 20;
        
        ObservableList<Integer> rows = FXCollections.observableList(IntStream.rangeClosed(1, numRows).boxed().toList());
        TableView<Integer> tv = new TableView<>(rows);
        for (int i = 0; i < numCols; i++) {
            TableColumn<Integer, String> col = new TableColumn<>();
            col.setCellFactory(ts -> new TableCell<>() {
                {
                    setPrefHeight(10); //does not apply values below about 25
                }
            });
            tv.getColumns().add(col);
        }
        Scene scene = new Scene(tv, 900, 600);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

[image: rows are clearly higher than 10 pixels]

**Version 2:**

Here I tried to use set `prefHeight` of a TableRow for selected rows, this sort of is the answer to my original question, but side effect is there is now empty space below the table, and those empty rows below the actual TableView even change their height if I drag columns to reorder them. I cannot access those rows as they are outside the range of the TableView. Not a satisfying situation.

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableCellTest3 extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        int numCols = 20;
        int numRows = 20;

        ObservableList<Integer> rows = FXCollections.observableList(IntStream.rangeClosed(1, numRows).boxed().toList());
        TableView<Integer> tv = new TableView<>(rows);
        for (int i = 0; i < numCols; i++) {
            TableColumn<Integer, String> col = new TableColumn<>();
            int ii = i;
            col.setCellValueFactory(cdf -> new SimpleStringProperty(String.valueOf(ii)));
            col.setCellFactory(ts -> new TableCell<>() {

                @Override public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);

                    if (item == null || empty) {
                        setText(null);

                    } else {
                        TableRow<Integer> row = getTableRow();
                        if (row != null) {
                            if (row.getItem() != null && row.getItem().intValue() < 10) {
                                row.setPrefHeight(15); //prefHeight of a row can be set low enough
                            } else {
                                row.setPrefHeight(25);
                            };
                        }
                        setText(item);
                    }
                }
            });
            tv.getColumns().add(col);
        }
        Scene scene = new Scene(tv, 900, 600);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

[image: strange space below the table]

**Version 3**

moving height setting code into TableRow's `updateItem` function instead of TableCell's `updateItem` function also produces empty space below the table, although this time those rows do not change their height when columns are dragged around.
Seems that whatever way, setting the `prefHeight` of a TableRow screws up the evaluation of how many filler rows are needed at the bottom of a table? Should this value really be dealt with at 'user level' ?

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableCellTest4 extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        int numCols = 20;
        int numRows = 20;

        ObservableList<Integer> rows = FXCollections.observableList(IntStream.rangeClosed(1, numRows).boxed().toList());
        TableView<Integer> tv = new TableView<>(rows);
        for (int i = 0; i < numCols; i++) {
            TableColumn<Integer, String> col = new TableColumn<>();
            int ii = i;
            col.setCellValueFactory(cdf -> new SimpleStringProperty(String.valueOf(ii)));
            tv.getColumns().add(col);
        }
        tv.setRowFactory(tview -> new TableRow<Integer>() {
            
            @Override public void updateItem(Integer item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (item != null && item < 10) {
                    setPrefHeight(15);
                } else {
                    setPrefHeight(25);
                }
            }
        });
        Scene scene = new Scene(tv, 900, 600);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you require the [rowFactory](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#rowFactoryProperty) property of class `javafx.scene.control.TableView` ?

Comment: indeed, a TableRow also has ´setPrefHeight()´, and setting this to values like 10 will then show up correctly. Side effect now is that as soon as I work on the height of a TableRow those empty rows below the actual table content go away, there is only empty space. That is the best I can get for now, trying to improve

Comment: What is a "low value".  JavaFX sizing hints are, minimum, preferred and maximum.  You are setting the preferred height, not the minimum, or some other combination.  Is that what you intended? Can you provide an image of what your desired output is and a description of how it changes (or doesn't change) depending on the available space.

Comment: In the example given, at the line `setPrefHeight(10)` values like 30 will produce rows of, well 30 pixels in height. 40 will be 40 pixels. But values of 10 or 15 or 20 will produce all the same row height of about 25 pixels

Comment: I had a look at that right away. So when you say rowFactory, you mean using the `updateItem` method of TableRow, right? This also produces empty space, which made me sceptical that messing around with that value is the way to go?

Comment: hmm .. looks weird, you might have hit a bug

Comment: .. similar for ListView, already in fx11 ..  the bug probably in VirtualFlow